# How to get context based on database type?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I have two **Context** as you see below.

```
public class AddressContext:DbContext{

    public AddressContext()
    {
        Name = "AddressContext";

    }
    public DbSet<address> addresses { get; set; }
}

public class NamesContext:DbContext{
    public NamesContext()
    {
        Name = "NamesContext";
    }
     public DbSet<Names> names { get; set; }
}
```

I also added `enum` for `DatabaseType`.

```
public enum DatabaseType
{
    address,
    names 
}
```

I would like to get `Context` based on `DatabaseType`.

I am not very familiar with the Factory or Strategy pattern in C#. I did try to write it but at the end I have to cast that context in order to use it.

What is the best way to get `Context` based on passing `DatabaseType` as parameter?

Comment: Factory pattern is used when all the concrete instances of different types have the same interface but implemented differently. In this case you have 2 classes having different members so it of course requires casting later. What you want here is impossible without casting **unless** somehow you just want to use some ***common members***  via an interface. Then all the classes should implement that interface and then you don't need casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DbContext GetContext(DatabaseType dbType)
{
    switch(dbType)
    {
        case DatabaseType.address:
            return new AddressContext();
        case DatabaseType.names:
            return new NamesContext();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected db type.");
    }
}
```

Comment: let's say i called `DbContext context = GetContext(DatabaseType.address);` I am still not able to access `address` property.

Comment: @Mvcdev That's correct. `DbContext` doesn't define that property.

Comment: I want to access those property that assign in context. What is the best way to get those property?

Comment: @Mvcdev Program against the concrete types.

Comment: could you please elaborate your above answer?

Comment: @Mvcdev This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface/384067#384067